# AngularFire - TypeError: Cannot read property '$add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I use Ionic and AngularFire for make a chat, but I have problem: the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$add' of undefined at Scope.$scope.sendChat (controllers.js:12)

prevents me to advance in my work. I don't understand where I can found the solution.

This is my code in controller.JS:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['firebase'])

.factory("Chats", function($firebaseArray) {
  var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://<MYFIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/chats");
  return $firebaseArray(chatsRef);
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
  function($scope, Chats, $rootScope) {

  $scope.sendChat = function(chat) {
      $scope.chats.$add({
        user: 'guest',
        message: chat.message

      });

      chat.message = "";

    };

}])
```

This is my code in HTML :

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <a class="item item-avatar">
        <img>
        <h2>{{ chat.user }}</h2>
        <p>{{ data.text }}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Message" ng-model="chat.message">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-assertive ion ion-ios-chatbubble" ng-click="sendChat(chat)"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can I found a charitable soul to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['firebase'])
    .factory("Chats", function($firebaseArray) {
        var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://<MYFIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/chats");
        return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
    })
    .controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Chats', '$firebaseArray',
        function($scope, $rootScope, Chats, $firebaseArray) {
            $scope.chats = Chats;
            $scope.sendChat = function(chat) {
                $scope.chats.$add({
                    user: 'guest',
                    message: chat.message

                });

                chat.message = "";

            };

        }
    ]);
```

Shouldn't you be returning `$firebaseArray(itemsRef)`instead of `$firebaseArray(chatsRef)` in Chats service?? A typo??

Injected, `Chats` service, `$firebaseArray` in controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks you, but I have another error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function controller.js:9
It's doesn't matter, I work in another project ... Thanks you all folk's !

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious issue is you need to either reference the $firebaseArray or $firebaseObject modules in your Controller to use the AngularFire methods.

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseArray',  function($scope, Chats, $rootScope, $firebaseArray) {
```

But if this is you complete Controller code theres other issues like you need to populate the $scope.chats object with your Service data

```
$scope.chats = Chats;
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I have use your solution, but I have another error now : "TypeError: $scope.chats.$add is not a function at Scope.$scope.sendChat (controllers.js:13)"
An idea ?

Comment: It maybe a good idea to setup a Plunkr or JSFiddle to collaborate on your issue, its a bit hard to debug JS code based on error messages